# Звідки пішло слово "вус"

Tags: етимологія

Звідки пішло слово "вус", які інші значення мало слово з якого воно утворилось?

[image]

Answer (score 5):

[Етимольоґічний словник української мови у 7 томах](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%95%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%96%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA_%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%97_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8)

[image]
[image]

Етимольоґічний словник української мови [Я. Рудницького](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%AF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2-%D0%91%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD_%D0%90%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87)

[image]
[image]

Comment: Дякую за відповідь, але мені дуже важко читати усі ці скорочення. Якби ви якось дали пояснення своїми словами.

Answer (score 3):

Побачив коментар до відповіді, а тому спробую розшифрувати. В [ЕСУМі](http://history.org.ua/LiberUA/EtSlUkrM_1982/EtSlUkrM_1982.pdf) пише, що слово "вус" походить із праслов'янської "vǫsъ" чи "ǫsъ". від якого також пішли російське "ус", больгарське "въс", білоруське "вус" тощо. Також вважається спорідненим із прусським словом "wanso" (перекладається як "перша борода"), древньоірландським "fés" (борода), "find" ("волосся"), грецьким "ἴονθος" ("бородата, кошлата").